# inverted index sets - querying key prefixes

Tags: search, redis

I'm using `Redis` in order to build an inverted index system for words and the documents that contains those words.

the setup is really simple: `Redis Sets` where the key of the `Set` is: **i:word**  and the values of the `Set` are the **documents ids** that have this word

let's say i have 2 sets: `i:example` and `i:result`

the `query - "example result"` will intersect `i:example` and `i:result` and return all the ids that have both *example and result* as members

but what i'm looking for is a way to perform (in efficient manner) a query like: **"ex res**". the result set should contain at least all the ids from the query **"example result"**

*Solutions that i thought of:*

- **create prefix sets of size 2**: `p:ex - contains {"example", "expertise", "ex"...}`. the lookup running time will not be a problem - `O(1)` to get the set and `O(n)` to check all elements in the set for words that start with the prefix (where `n = set.size()`) but i worry about the added size price.
- **Using scan**: but i'm not sure about the running time - query like `scan 0 match ex*` will take O(n) [where n is the number of keys in the db](http://redis.io/commands/scan)? I know redis is fast but it's probably not an optimized solution for query like **"ex machi cont"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to go about this is the first approach you had mentioned, but usually you'd go with segments that are 3+ chars long. Note that you'll need to have a set for each segment, i.e.g. `i:exa`, `i:exam`, `i:examp`, `i:exampl` and of course `i:example`.

This will naturally take up space in your database (hence the suggestion to start at 3 rather than 2 characters). A possible tweak is to keep in the i:len(3) sets only references to i:len(4+) sets instead of document ids. This will required more read operations but will have significant savings in terms of RAM.

You should explore v2.8.9's addition of lexicographical ranges for Sorted Sets. By calling [`ZRANGEBYLEX`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex) you can get ranges of members (i.e.g. all the words that start with ex). While this could be useful in this context by itself, consider that you can also use your Sorted Set's members creatively to encode a word and its document reference. This can help you get over the "loss" of the score (since all scores need to be the same for lexicographical ordering to work). For example, assuming the words "bed" and "beg" in docs 1 and 2:

```
ZADD index 0 "beg:1" 0 "bed:2"
```

Lastly, here's a little something to think about too - adding suffix searching (i.e.g, everything that ends with "ample"): https://redislabs.com/blog/how-to-use-redis-at-least-x1000-more-efficiently